# How do I remove the spaces from final output ciphertext?

Tags: c, arrays, string, encryption

How do I remove the spaces between the ciphertext so it prints as a single line of numbers? Example output: ## ## ## ## ## ## > ############

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[6];
  int i=0;
  int key;

  printf("Enter 6 letter password (all caps): ");
  scanf("%s",str);

  printf ("Enter a single digit cipher key (between 2-8):");
  scanf ("%d", &key);
  printf("The ciphertext is: ");
  while(str[i])
    printf("%d ",str[i++]+key);

  return 0;
}
```

Example :

```
Enter 6 letter password (all caps): ISABEL
Enter a single digit cipher key (between 2-8):7
The ciphertext is: 80 90 72 73 76 83
```

Comment: By changing `"%d "` with a space, to `"%d"` without a space.

Comment: Who is "*ISABEL*"? ;>

Comment: OT: "*`char str[6]; .... "Enter 6 letter password ...`*" no, only five are allowed. Mind the `0`-terminator.

Comment: and protect it with `scanf("%6s",str);` after correcting the string size.

Comment: @alk and who is _PZHILS_ ? ^^

Comment: Attempting to print as 12 '#' will be confusing when `str[i++]+key >= 100`.  Suppose the "all caps" hopes to prevent that.

Comment: @chux yes, but in 'standard' ascii case the max upped case is 'Z' and 'Z'+8 = 98, the input string is in uppercase (this is how I understood _caps_)

Comment: @bruno The concern is that the "all caps" is 1) only a suggestion, nothing in code insures that and 2) capital letters do exist outside the ASCII range.  Of course for learner code this may not be important - we just assume the user will not enter challenging text.  Yet with that same line of design, we might as well use `gets()`  or `scanf("%s",str);` rather than the better [`scanf("%6s", str)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278138/2410359).

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand you want something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str[7];

  printf("Enter 6 letter password (all caps): ");

  if ((scanf("%6s", str) != 1) || (strlen(str) != 6)) {
    puts("invalid input");
    return 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i) {
    if (!isupper(str[i])) {
      printf("'%c' is not an uppercase character\n", str[i]);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int key;

  printf ("Enter a single digit cipher key (between 2-8):");
  if ((scanf ("%d", &key) != 1) || (key < 2) || (key > 8)) {
    puts("invalid value");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("The ciphertext is (ascii) :");
  for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    printf("%c", str[i]+key);
  putchar('\n');

  printf("The ciphertext is (codes) :");
  for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    printf("%02d", str[i]+key);
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
Enter 6 letter password (all caps): ISABEL
Enter a single digit cipher key (between 2-8):7
The ciphertext is (ascii) :PZHILS
The ciphertext is (codes) :809072737683
```

Comment: @StephenJohnson change your passwords, we know all what you use ^^

Comment: @chux ^^ who never did ?